# Scrollify stop at particular section

Tags: jquery, jquery-scrollify

I have button at top. On that button click, I have to scroll the body upto that div using scrolltop animation. Whenever i click, called div slightly goes in upper direction. sometimes next section is appeared on button click. It should be stopped at that div.

Comment: You won't be able to use scrollTop animations with Scrollify. Scrollify handles all scroll animation for you.

Comment: I have used $(scrollify).move(); but, nothing happend.

Comment: That means you don't have it set up correctly.

Comment: how can i move to next section on button click. target div is at bottom.

Comment: Use the move method

Comment: $('button.apply').click(function(){
    jQuery.scrollify.move('#opening');
} I have used this code for move. but nothing happed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/140160/discussion-between-gt06-and-luke-haas).